# Display images and descriptions in VueJs

Tags: json, vue.js

I am creating a blog site using VueJs and wagtail. I am getting pages and images data in Json.
I need to display data as

description: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

img: something.jpg

description: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

img: something.jpg

How Can I do it? 
Here is my code. In my code i cannot display right

```
<template>
<div class="app">
  <div>
    <b-card-group deck v-for="item in results" :key="item.id">
      <b-card
        border-variant="primary"
      >
        <b-card-text>
          <div v-for="block in item.body" :key="block.id">
            <div v-if="block.type == 'heading'">
              <h2>{{block.value}}</h2>
            </div>
               <div v-for="image in images" :key="image.id">
                 <div v-if="block.type == 'image'">
                 <img :src="'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + image.meta.download_url" alt="">
               </div>
              <!-- <img :src="'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' + block.value"> -->
            </div>
             <div v-if="block.type == 'paragraph'">
              <h2 v-html="block.value">{{block.value}}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </b-card-text>
      </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
      results: null,
      image_path: null,
      tags: null,
      title: null,
      images: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/pages/?type=news.NewsPage&fields=intro,body,image_thumbnail')
      .then((response) => {
        this.results = response.data.items
      })
      .catch((error) => (
        console.log(error)
      ))
  },
  created () {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/images/')
      .then((response) => {
        this.images = response.data.items
      })
      .catch((error) => (
        console.log(error)
      ))
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.app{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card{
  border: 2px solid black;

}
  p{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  }
  h2{
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing? what do you see currently? You seem to have two calls to the server, in created and mounted. the images array doesn't seem linked to the data items?

Comment: i uploaded 3 images on backend. in frontend i get 3 times like (description and 3 images), (description and 3 images), (description and 3 images)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues with this code:

1) You are loading the ajax data in created and mounted. The images do not link to the data,

2) You also need to sort out the indenting, because I think you're divs are not aligned as you possibly intend. Note in the images, you are looping over the this.images property which is loaded from the ajax. However, don't the images come from the outer object you are iterating over? Or are you intending to repeat the same set of images over each time you iterate a blog item?

Comment: How can i link images to the data? what is the right way?

Comment: you have two ajax calls, one gets data, one gets images. There seems to be no link for this. Don't you have the image data on the blog items? Can you post your the data for that method?